# Chromium on Kubuntu Stops Rendering Fonts After A While

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, snap, chromium

Environment:
Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Chromium Version 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) snap (64-bit) (happened on older versions, too)

I use Chromium a lot. I regularly have 50+ tabs open over several windows. I use private mode for day to day information finding activities, and normal mode for lots of online service with login.

After a few days, sometimes even weeks, of uptime I find Chromium not rendering new tabs correctly anymore. For all I can tell, it only renders monospaced fonts and numbers. Please see attached screenshot for an example. Once started, this affects all new tabs. The only way to get out of this is to restart Chromium.

Found nothing useful in `~/.xsession-errors` and no related known issues on the internet. I *think* I tried out disabling hardware acceleration, but am not 100% sure at this time. I don't think it's related to snap updates happening in the background. Those used to cause problems a few months ago.

**Update:** It may after all be related to Snap. Found in JournalD today:

```
Mounting Mount unit for chromium, revision 1942...
Mounted Mount unit for chromium, revision 1942.
...
snap-chromium-1912.mount: Succeeded.
snap-chromium-1912.mount: Succeeded.
...
Started snap.chromium.hook.configure.082d81d7-319c-425e-bda1-42539717b314.scope.
snap.chromium.hook.configure.082d81d7-319c-425e-bda1-42539717b314.scope: Succeeded.
```

and I ran into the problem a few minutes later.

Any pointers highly appreciated.

[image: weird Chromium rendering issue example]

Comment: I've had this happen to me as well on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS using Gnome 3.36.8